# file upload using CCK not showing nid reference

Tags: files

I have uploaded the image using CCk  the file path is stored in file table but where i can find the nid and fid for the uploaded file?

Comment: if we upload the file using default file attachment then it store the file path in file table and fid and nid in upload table. but i have use cck to upload the file which store my image path in file table but im not able to find the nid and fid reference in another table.

Comment: you mean in which table do you find the nid and fid values?

Comment: yes im not able to find the nid and fid for cck uploaded images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets say you have a content type X. You add a field Y to X to upload a file (using filefield or image etc) then you will find the nid and fid in the field table created by cck. 
This table will be something like content_field_Y which should have the nid and fid that you desire.

Update: To clarify the column name will not be simply fid, but will be the machine name of the field suffixed with _value, _nid etc.

Comment: thank you so much Dipen i got the nid but where can i find the fid for uploaded image

Comment: the same table should contain the fid. I'd wanna backup and understand what is that you are trying to do? There are lot of ways of finding the fid of file attached to a node, for instance $node will also have that information. In the database, it should be in the corresponding field table (like I mentioned above) and there should be a column in the table which would be something like field_Y_fid etc ( in drupal 6 it should be the fourth column)

Comment: problem solved got the fid in the same table, thanks for the help